# Reloading ActiveRecord objects in Rspec (particularly after a POST request)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have a `time_zone` attribute on my `User` model which tracks the user's preferred time_zone. This starts off as `nil` by default.

On their personal EDIT page, the user can change their timezone by selecting another one from a dropdown list.

My test is as follows -

```
it "updates the user's time zone on submit" do
  # Creates with FactoryGirl
  @user = create(:user)

  # BEFORE state confirmation
  expect(@user.time_zone).to be_nil

  # Simulate the user selecting a timezone from the dropdown on their edit page. 
  # Capybara is used for selection and clicking.
  visit edit_profile_path
  select_time_zone_from_dropdown("America/New_York")

  # Submit, which sends a POST request to update the User model
  click_button("Submit")

  # AFTER state confirmation - this FAILS
  # Apparently the reload doesn't work and `time_zone` is still set to
  # nil for this user 
  @user.reload
  expect(@user.time_zone).to eq("America/New_York")
end
```

As you can see, the test fails because the `time_zone` is never updated for this User record.

Here's what's strange -

1. In the database, the value correctly DOES change. It's just the `ActiveRecord` object which doesn't
2. To get around #1, I tried reloading the object attributes, but no luck
3. If I pause it with `binding.pry` just after the `reload` and run `@user.reload` **manually**, it works. So it's just while running during the test suite that it's not working.

Is there something strange going on here with how the value is cached and reloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the @user object is the one being changed? How does "edit_profile_path" know which user to edit?

Comment: Maybe it's a timing issue, could you add a `expect(page).to have('some_selector')` and then `@user.reload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens because Capybara uses a different connection to database. I had this problem and solved using this patch, which forces all threads to use the same connection.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end

# Forces all threads to share the same connection. This works on
# Capybara because it starts the web server in a thread.
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/470808)

Make sure to require this code in your `spec_helper` file

Comment: Thank you, that seems like what's happening. I found some more literature on it here - https://gist.github.com/josevalim/470808 - still appears to be somewhat of an issue! What I'm still confused about is why `user.reload` inside the test doesn't work. Even if it's a different connection that what Capybara is using, it should fundamentally re-pull all info from the DB (which has been updated correctly), so shouldn't that alone solve the issue? Thanks again!  (Edit: to clarify, it DOES work with your fix + `user.reload`. I just meant that I'd expect it to work without your patch, right?)

Comment: @user2490003, the problem before the patch occurs because before each test, rspec opens an transaction and rollback it at the end. Then, when you call `user.reload` inside the test, the transaction is open and the changes aren't committed to database.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you again. You saved me a lot of hair-pulling